# How to use custom theme/colors for Svelte Material UI (SMUI) components in Sapper project?

Tags: sass, material-ui, svelte, sapper

I've followed [the instructions](https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui) for using Svelte Material UI (SMUI) in a Sapper project.

I can import and use SMUI components with the default theme/colors if I leave `src/theme/_smui-theme.scss` blank. When I include the following code suggested by SMUI in this file to use custom colors, it tells me `Can't find stylesheet to import.`

```
@use "@material/theme" with (
    $primary: #5466F9,
    $secondary: #14a564,
    $surface: #fff,
    $background: #fff
);
```

I can confirm that the `@material/theme` directory does exist inside of node_modules. Can anyone help me understand why this would be causing such an error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Svelte Material UI was recently updated (improved performance!) and the latest [install instructions](https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui/blob/master/INSTALL.md) work well for Sapper. If you are dealing with a similar error in a Sapper app, I would recommend the following steps:

1. uninstall rollup-plugin-postcss and sass
2. uninstall v2 SMUI components, e.g. `npm uninstall @smui/textfield`
3. install v3 SMUI components, e.g. `npm install --save-dev @smui/textfield`
4. follow the install instructions referenced above for sapper

This fixed it for me to allow me to provide a custom theme in `src/theme/_smui-theme.scss`

For non-sapper projects [this may work](https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui/issues/218). It was the inspiration beyond this fix above for sapper. Thanks to Hunter, the creator of SMUI, for his help in fixing this and for an awesome library!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the same issue as [this one](https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui/issues/218) on the GitHub issue tracker:

The solution should be to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and reinstall.

```
rm -r node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```